# Sum columns in a new column next to the selection

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to sum a number of columns together in a new column.

I have been able to get to the point where I take A+B and place the values in C. However, the actual columns I will need to sum vary. Is there a way I can edit my code so that any selected columns can be summed in a new column to the right of the selection?

For example. If I select columns B-D, it would insert a new column in E that houses the sums of columns B,C, and D. Or if I selected E-F, it would insert a new column in G that houses the sums of columns E and F.

```
Sub SumColumns()

Lastrow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).row

For i = 1 To Lastrow
    Range("C" & i).Value = Range("A" & i).Value + Range("B" & i).Value
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Is there a reason you are not using a formula (ex: `SUM(A1:B10`) to do this? It will have the advantage of taking any subsequent changes to the values summed into account

Comment: I'm not just using the formula because the ranges change. A isn't always included. It may just be C-D or I-J or L-Z, it's impossible to tell. So I need to account for a specific range and sum the range of columns according to the selection.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you want to sum vertically all cells in a row starting from column A.

Try this (some tips and comments are in code):

```
'use this in order to avoid errors
Option Explicit

Sub SumColumns()
    'always declare variables!
    Dim LastRow As Long, i As Long, ws As Worksheet, lastCol As Long, firstCol As Long
    'if you can, avoid using ActiveSheet, Selection, etc. it's prone to errors
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    i = 1
    Do
        firstCol = ws.Cells(i, 1).End(xlToRight).Column
        lastCol = ws.Cells(i, ws.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        'there isn't any filled cells in a row
        If lastCol = 1 Then Exit Do

        ws.Cells(i, lastCol + 1).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(ws.Range(ws.Cells(i, firstCol), ws.Cells(i, lastCol)))

        i = i + 1
    Loop While True

End Sub
```

Before and after:

[image]

Comment: This doesn't work if the selected area doesn't contain column A - you'll have to make that `LastRow` dynamic :)

Comment: @dwirony I get your point and you're completely right, but I got strong suspicion it will suffice :)

Comment: This is good but I don't always include column A. The selected columns could vary. It may be A-D or L-Z or G-J. There's no way to predict it. So it would need to identify a range and then add a column (so I don't delete data) and sum the values in this new column.

Comment: @Valborg Can there be any empty rows?

Comment: @MichałTurczyn the data ranges will not contain any empty rows but it's possible that an entire row between the columns sums to zero.

Comment: @Valborg Try updated code. The stop condition for loop is that there will be a row without any filled cells.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my (rather sloppy) solution:

```
Sub Test()

Dim col1 As String, col2 As String, lastrow As Long

col1 = Split(Selection.Address, "$")(1)
col2 = Split(Selection.Address, "$")(3)

lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, col2).End(xlUp).Row

Columns(col2 & ":" & col2).Offset(0, 1).Insert Shift:=xlToRight

For i = 1 To lastrow
    Range(col2 & i).Offset(0, 1).Value = WorksheetFunction.Sum(Range(col1 & i & ":" & col2 & i))
Next i

End Sub
```

I say this is sloppy, because if you have the *entire* column selected, you won't `Split` out the column values appropriately. So it depends on how you're trying to do this.

[image: img1]

Answer (score 0):

This procedure will let you select any range.  It will add a column at the end of the range and sum each row to the new column.

```
Sub test()
    Call InsertSumCol(Sheet1.Range("B2:E4"))
    Call InsertSumCol(Sheet2.Range("E1:F3"))
End Sub

Private Sub InsertSumCol(ByVal oRange As Range)

    'Add Sum Column to end of Range
    oRange.Worksheet.Columns(oRange.Column + oRange.Columns.Count).Insert shift:=xlToRight

    ' Sum Each Row in Range
    Dim oRow As Range
    For Each oRow In oRange.Rows
        oRow.Cells(1, oRow.Columns.Count + 1) = WorksheetFunction.Sum(oRow)
    Next

End Sub
```